# How to create different workspace for different users in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Can someone help me to understand , as how can i create different workspace for different users in Laravel ?

I have created an authentication and login system , but whenever i login with different user name , it point me to same workspace?

Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you dividing users based on a role column or something else?

Comment: @Makdous no , i am not , could you please explain more on this as how i can accomplish  ?

Comment: So you want to redirect each user to a certain view, but the question is what is the thing that differentiate users from each other.

Comment: @Makdous , the user id is email which is authenticated , once user authenticates he should login to its own work space

Comment: so these workspaces of users, is it different in data only or in layout of the view?

Answer (score 0):

you could overwrite the **redirectPath** function in the **AuthController** and depending on a certain feature of the user redirects it to the corresponding view

```html
public function redirectPath()
{
    if (\Auth::user()->role == 'admin') {
        return "/dashboard";
        // or return route('my_route');
    }

    return "/home";
    // or return route('my_route_home');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made these changes and it worked :

Inside home controller i added  the logic that determines which user and thus which workspace to load.

Something like

```
public function index()
{
    $workspace = Workspace::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
    //Do what it is you want to do with the workspace. 
}
```